# Big Oh Notation O((log n)^k) = O(log n)?

Tags: big-o, proof

In big-O notation is `O((log n)^k) = O(log n)`, where `k` is some constant (e.g. the number of logarithmic for loops), true?

I was told by my professor that this statement was true, however he said it will be proved later in the course. I was wondering if any of you could demonstrate its validity or have a link where I could confirm if it is true.

Comment: Better ask this at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is _k_? A constant? Another parameter describing the problem size? If _k_ is applied to the entire logarithm, did you intend to write O((log _n_) ^ _k_) instead?

Comment: Changes made, k is a constant.

Comment: @user1084113: It's possible that you didn't understand your professor correctly, or that he goofed. Either way, please see my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(1) It is true that O(log(n^k)) = O(log n).

(2) It is false that O(log^k(n)) (also written O((log n)^k)) = O(log n).

Observation: (1) has been proven by nmjohn.

Exercise: prove (2). (*Hint: f(n) = log^2 n is O(log^2 n). Is it O(log n)? What is a sufficiently large constant c such that, for all n greater than n0, c log n > log^2 n?*)

EDIT:

On a related note, anybody who finds this question helpful and/or interesting should go show some love for the new "Computer Science" StackExchange site. Here's a link. Go make this new place a reality!

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=rpnXA1_2BNYzXN85c5ibxQ2

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure he didn't mean O(log n^k), because that equals O(k*log n) = k*O(log n) = O(log n).

Comment: the problem was 2 logarithmic for loops, and he explicitly put the brackets there to indicate k is applied to the entire log

Answer (score -1):

O(log *n*) is a class of functions. You cannot perform computations such as ^*k* on it. Thus, the term O(log *n*)^*k* does not even look sensible to me.

Comment: It is an answer, @Patrick87. It literally meant ‘Your question is bogus and cannot be answered’, which was true at the time.